# Separate a part of a python output then convert it into another unit

Tags: python, memory, psutil

I know the title makes it sounds all complicated, but it is actually simple.

So I am trying to collect system data with python, and I am using the psutil module with python 3.6. I want to find used memory, so I did the command `psutil.virtual_memory()`. However, the output I got was `svmem(total=8535257088, available=3911340032, percent=54.2, used=4623917056, free=3911340032)`.

I only want to keep the `used=4623917056` part of the output. How would I seperate that part from the output?

Also, `used=4623917056` is in bytes. I want to convert it to gigabytes, and keep the result to the 3 most significant digits (in this case it would be 4.62). How would I do this as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the simplest one:

```
round(psutil.virtual_memory().used /(1024 ** 3),2)
```

in python [round()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) function will have two arguments one is value itself and other is a number of digits you want to keep after the decimal.

Answer (score 1):

```
vm = psutil.virtual_memory()
used_gb = vm.used / (1024 ** 3)
```

Comment: Thanks. However, this does not keep the first 3 digits. I just get the full thing (4.62......)

Comment: You're welcome.  Look at the format string options here: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#formatspec - maybe you'll find one that suits you.